# Java EE Tomcat DefaultServlet extension not working for static files

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm facing the problem of writing a web app in Java EE based on Servlets. Everything's ok but I can not figure out how to attach `js` and `css` files to my `html` pages properly. I've read some answers and posts on the web about this and I don't want to write my own servlets to do this as Tomcat provides `DefaultServlet` as far as I know and it serves what I want. Now, I tried to write implementation of this class and here it goes:

```
package xx.xx.xx;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/js/*","/css/*","/libs/*"})
public class StaticContent extends DefaultServlet {

    public StaticContent() {
        super();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        File f = new File(StaticContent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()+"../css/global.css");
        System.out.println("_____HERE " + request.getRequestURL() + " | " + f.exists());
        super.doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

I don't get it. It still doesn't work. The java filesystem recognizes it and returns `true` on `file.exists()` but the server does not. When I try to access it from the browser it also fails wih `404`. Any ideas what should I do here? The asset files are just next to the `html`s in `WEB-INF`.

Comment: I tried absolute path, and realtive with and without `./`. None of this work :c

Answer (score 0):

ok I got this working here's my `doGet` method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String arr[] = request.getRequestURL().toString().split("/");
    String file = arr[arr.length-1];
    String folder = arr[arr.length-2];
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/"+folder+"/"+file).forward(request, response);
}
```